# Yii2: передача конкретного сценария при обновлении данных

Tags: yii2

Можно ли как-то определить конкретный сценарий валидации данных в модель? В оф.документации есть только при создании новой записи, а для обновления не нашел.

Comment: немного некорректно составил вопрос: передать конкретный сценарий необходимо на обновление записи в таблице

Comment: Для редактирования/дополнения/уточнения вопроса есть ссылка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/836989/edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создание новой или обновление существующей модели не играет роли. Сценарий необходимо установить перед загрузкой данных в модель. Сделать это можно подобным образом.

```
$this->model->setScenario($this->model::SCENARIO_FEEDBACK_TRANSFER);
$model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post());
```